# Visibility problem of static vars with getStaticProperties and getStaticPropertyValue ReflectionClass functions

Tags: php

```
class RCE
{
    protected static $pri = 'Private static property';
    protected static $pro = 'Protected static property';
    public static $pub = 'Public static property';
}
$rce = new ReflectionClass('RCE');

//var_dump($rce->getStaticPropertyValue('pri')); //ReflectionException
//var_dump($rce->getStaticPropertyValue('pro')); //ReflectionException
var_dump($rce->getStaticPropertyValue('pub'));
```

In the code, its obvious, that in the current context i cant access private or protected properties. No problem. i understand.

```
class RCE
{
    protected static $pri = 'Private static property';
    protected static $pro = 'Protected static property';
    public static $pub = 'Public static property';
}
$rce = new ReflectionClass('RCE');

var_dump($rce->getStaticProperties());
```

But, in this code, it was also not supposed to give me private or protected properties. 
it does show all static properties of `RCE` class (even protected and private).

So, My question is,

- Why `getStaticProperties` show all private and protected, wasn't it suppsed to hide it.??
- If it wasn't, then why `getStaticPropertyValue` hides protected and private properties. shouldn't it, show all properties like `getStaticProperies`??

and, Is there any manual to get its documentation, php's official manual seems not to be documented, yet.

Comment: **getStaticPropertyValue** has a security level different from the **getStaticProperties** method.

Answer (score 0):

The function **getStaticProperties** returns the static properties of the class. All it does is returning a list of static properties, **you are not trying to access them**.

That's the difference with the **getStaticPropertyValue** call. With **getStaticPropertyValue** you are trying to access the value of a property, which in this case is protected. The public, protected and private annotations are meant to show the "level" of access it has. But this you already knew.

Read more about visibility here:
http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php

Comment: whats the difference between accesing protected property and getting all properties??

Comment: The difference is wether you're trying to access a property or not. I edited my answer and added a link. It explains property visibility. If my answer helped you, please mark it as the accepted answer so that other people know it as well.